# JSF + Primeryface как вывести данные на страницу

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Пытаюсь вывести всех Pet на странице после регистрации пользователя,но не выводится ничего. Вопросы к знатокам:

1  здесь я создаю кнопку и поле для ввода имени

```
 <p:commandButton value="create pet" id="ajax" update="growl" action ="#{firstPage.buttonAction}"
                         styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
            <h:inputText value="#{firstPage.petName}"/>
```

как мне сделать,чтобы при нажатии выводили все pet этого customer?

2 Должно ли быть все в одной форме? или нужно для каждого действия создавать новуб форму.

3 Я прочел про activity, но не могу понять, как его приминять для конкретной кнопки.

мой код

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="growl" life="2000"/>

        <p:commandButton value="create pet" id="ajax" update="growl" action ="#{firstPage.buttonAction}"
                         styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
            <h:inputText value="#{firstPage.petName}"/>

        <p:panel header="Pets" id="addedPets">

           <p:dataTable value="#{customer.pets}" var="pet">
               <p:column>
                   <h:column>
                       #{pet}
                   </h:column>
                   <h:outputText value="#{customer.id}">

                   </h:outputText>
               </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

сам бин

```
@Named
@ManagedBean
public class FirstPage {

    @EJB
    private PetManager petManager;

    private String petName;

    public String getPetName() {
        return petName;
    }

    public void setPetName(String petName) {
        this.petName = petName;
    }

    public PetManager getPetManager() {
        return petManager;
    }

    public void setPetManager(PetManager petManager) {
        this.petManager = petManager;
    }

    public void buttonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        petManager.createPet(FacesUtils.getUserId(), petName);
        System.out.println("Pet createt");
    }

}
```

класс для создании кнопки

```
  @Stateful
public class PetManager {

    @EJB
    private PetRepository petRepository;

    @EJB
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public void createPet(Integer customerId, String name) {
        Pet pet = petRepository.createPet(name);
        customerRepository.addPetToCustomer(customerId, pet);
    }

}
```

клиент

```
@Entity(name = "CUSTOMER")
@Named
public class Customer {

    public static final String FIND_BY_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD = "findByUsernameAndPassword";
   /* @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;*/

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @Unique
    private String login;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Pet> pets;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Pet> getPets() {
     /*   List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT  pet FROM CUSTOMER");
        List<Customer> customerList = query.getResultList();
        for (Customer customer: customerList){
            pets.add((Pet) customer.getPets());
        }*/
    // Query query = entityManager.createQuery("  SELECT pets FROM CUSTOMER  ");
     //return  query.getResultList();
       return pets;
    }

    public void setPets(List<Pet> pets) {
        this.pets = pets;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <p:commandButton value="create pet" id="ajax" update="addedPets" actionListener ="#{firstPage.buttonAction}"
                         styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
            <h:inputText value="#{firstPage.petName}"/>

        <p:panel header="Pets" id="addedPets">

           <p:dataTable value="#{firstPage.pets}" var="pet" >
               <p:column>
                   <h:outputText value="#{pet.name}" id="addPets" >
                   </h:outputText>
               </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

        </p:panel>
```

а так же

```
 public void buttonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        petManager.createPet(FacesUtils.getUserId(), petName);
    }

    public Collection<Pet> getPets() {

        return customerManager.getPetsForCustomer(FacesUtils.getUserId());
    }
```